# private OnClickListener clickFunction = new OnClickListener(){stmt; }

Tags: java, android

I was trying a sample application on android. I could able to get the output.

### studentFormsActiviyt.java

```
package com.example.android.accelerometerplay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

public class StudentFormsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // To specify the actions of the Buttons
        Button accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton1);
        Button reject = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);

        accept.setOnClickListener(clickFunction);
        reject.setOnClickListener(clickFunction);
    }

    private OnClickListener clickFunction = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text;

            switch(v.getId()){
               case R.id.myButton1: text="accept was pushed"; 
                                    break;
               case R.id.myButton2: text="reject was pushed"; 
                                    break;
               default: text="We didn't know what was pressed :(";  
            }

            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
 }
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/myLabel"
    android:text="Name of the student:" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/myLabel" 
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton1"
    android:text="Accept:" 
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/myText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton2"
    android:text="Reject:" 
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/myButton1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/myButton1"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I could not understand this definition of the class "private OnClickListener clickFunction = new OnClickListener(){stmt; }". we used to declare the class as private class classname{stmt}; and then used to create the instance of the class. But in the above first declaration they are creating instance of the class and then they are defining.
why are they doing like this. Please help me to understand.

Comment: [Different Ways To Handle Clicks](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a69/Different-Ways-To-Handle-Clicks.html)

Comment: Yow want implement on click listener

Answer (score 2):

OnClickListener is an interface. When the new operator is used on that interface you are actually providing an implementation for that interface (an anonymous inner-class). The class implementation is anonymous because you are not providing a name for it at compile time and a name for it will be assigned at run time. You could also provide an explicit implementation for it as a private inner class which implements the OnClickListener interface.

```
    package com.example.android.accelerometerplay;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.content.Context;

    public class StudentFormsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // To specify the actions of the Buttons
    Button accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton1);
    Button reject = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);

    accept.setOnClickListener(clickFunction);
    reject.setOnClickListener(clickFunction);
}

private OnClickListener clickFunction = new OnClickClass();

private class OnClickClass implements OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text;

        switch(v.getId()){
           case R.id.myButton1: text="accept was pushed"; 
                                break;
           case R.id.myButton2: text="reject was pushed"; 
                                break;
           default: text="We didn't know what was pressed :(";  
        }

        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
        toast.show();

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hope things are clear now.. When you instantiate an interface or abstract class you have to provide an implementation for the abstract methods, and the JRE will create a run time "type" for your newly instantiated object...
Check this out : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a C# developer and couldn't understand how the new operator could be used on an interface.  Your answer helped clear it up for me.  Thanks for the link also.

Answer (score 1):

```
private OnClickListener clickFunction = new OnClickListener(){stmt; }
```

but this is not a definition of private class .. it a definition of private member class.

it the same like:

```
//declaring member class
private OnClickListener clickFunction;

private OnClickListener clickFunctionMake(){
    return new OnClickListener(){stmt; };
}

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//.....initializing member class
        clickFunction=clickFunctionMake();
///....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private OnClickListener clickFunction = new OnClickListener(){stmt; }
```

In above statement **OnClickListener** is not class its an **Interface**, actually the interface in **android.view.View** class. We can't instantiate any Interface by using **new** keyword.

In the code you posted here, he is creating instance **clickFunction** by implementing the **View.OnClickListener** Interface, so he implemented the method **onClick** also.

He is using the single instance **clickFunction** for two buttons to eliminate two listeners.

I hope you understand this and it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would code everything almost exactly like Alex Calugarescu's answer.  However, I usually create the handler inside the main class.  Also instead of using breaks, I prefer using if/else statements.  Same result just a different take on using private inner classes.

```
package com.example.android.accelerometerplay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StudentFormsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // To specify the actions of the Buttons
    Button accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton1);
    Button reject = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);

    ButtonHandler buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();

    accept.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
    reject.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View v){
        CharSequence text;

        if(v.getId()==R.id.myButton1)
           text="accept was pushed"; 
        else if(v.getId()==R.id.myButton2)
           text="reject was pushed"; 
        else
           text="We didn't know what was pressed :(";

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```